# my hamburger got away (bootstrap) issue - menu showing on full and small screen but not on tablet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, breakpoints

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while but I am not a bootstrap expert, its a mini site I am making which is in blazor but I have used a boostrap template in it, everything works apart from this one thing.

The full menus shows on full screen, and burger menu shows on a small screen but nothing inbetween, both menus do not appear on I guess a tablet size.

I have tried changing the css but nothing seems to have an impact

If anyone has a clue that would be fantastic, Thank You

You can see the issue on this site (still a work in progress)

https://passvault.co.uk/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing "max-width" with "min-width" of media queries in your CSS file. I don't usually work with bootstrap but I think that it's the problem here.